# VS Code keeps placing breakpoints in the JS files when debugging typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, debugging

when debugging a typescript application, everything is fine until i set a breakpoint. when i set one, the breakpoint appears to be placed in the **typescript** file but once it compiles, the breakpoint will move to the corresponding place in the .js file. when the breakpoint is hit, it will show me the **javascript** (JS) code.

- all extensions are disabled
- i have tried removing compiler flags and changing position of import statements
- there were a few different solutions online which i tried like these:
  https://pkief.medium.com/how-to-debug-typescript-with-vs-code-9cec93b4ae56
  and this one:
  [Visual Studio code breakpoint not working on Node.js using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196019/visual-studio-code-breakpoint-not-working-on-node-js-using-typescript)

i expected to be able to debug typescript in the typescript source files, not the javascript ones.

this is the repository i am working on:
https://github.com/JohnHeikens/IntelliSkript

Comment: i have ' "sourcemaps": true' on all 3 configurations.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that there are two options for sourcemaps:
one in `tsconfig.json` (called 'sourceMap') and one in `launch.json.` (called 'sourceMaps').