# VSCode debugger not stopping at breakpoint in another folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, tsx

I have a project with two folders using TypeScript, looks like this:
[image]

I'm just running a `manual.ts` file, which just imports a function in the other folder and runs it (it's standalone) using the `tsx` runner. It's really simple:

```
import { extractValuesAndPerks } from "../data-insights-tasks/ingest-jobs/src/scrapers/openaiExtractor";
import data from "./data";

async function main() {
  const res = await extractValuesAndPerks(data);
  console.log(res);
}
main();
```

Here's my launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Current file (TS)",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/tsx/dist/cli.js",
      "args": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/index"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The function runs fine but I can't step into it nor will it stop at a breakpoint inside. The breakpoint is red before running but when I start the debugging process, it say `Unbound breakpoint`:

[image]

Is there a specific configuration for handling multiple folders?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196019/visual-studio-code-breakpoint-not-working-on-node-js-using-typescript